# Python - Save data to a file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to save the data tables to a txt file instead of showing the result on the console. However, my code result me to NONE in the txt file... Can someone please help me:

Result that I would like to save to the txt file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json

# Input
thislist = ["AAPL"]
for symbol in thislist:
    print ('Getting data for ' + symbol + '...\n')
# Set up scraper
url1 = ("http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getFinancePart.html?&callback=xxx&t=" + symbol.lower())
url2 = ("http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getKeyStatPart.html?&callback=xxx&t=" + symbol.lower())

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(json.loads(re.findall(r'xxx\((.*)\)', requests.get(url1).text)[0])['componentData'], 'lxml')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(json.loads(re.findall(r'xxx\((.*)\)', requests.get(url2).text)[0])['componentData'], 'lxml')

def print_table(soup):

    for i, tr in enumerate(soup.select('tr')):

        row_data = [td.text for td in tr.select('td, th') if td.text]

        if not row_data:
            continue

        if len(row_data) < 12:
            row_data = ['X'] + row_data

        for j, td in enumerate(row_data):
            if j==0:
                print('{: >30}'.format(td), end='|')
            else:
                print('{: ^12}'.format(td), end='|')
        print()
  
print_table(soup1)

print()

print_table(soup2)
```

So I have written the following code to save it to a txt file but the result is "NONE" in the txt file but the result is shown on the console:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json

# Input
thislist = ["AAPL"]
for symbol in thislist:
    print ('Getting data for ' + symbol + '...\n')

    # Set up scraper
    url1 = ("http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getFinancePart.html?&callback=xxx&t=" + symbol.lower())
    url2 = ("http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getKeyStatPart.html?&callback=xxx&t=" + symbol.lower())
    
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(json.loads(re.findall(r'xxx\((.*)\)', requests.get(url1).text)[0])['componentData'], 'lxml')
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(json.loads(re.findall(r'xxx\((.*)\)', requests.get(url2).text)[0])['componentData'], 'lxml')
    
    def print_table(soup):
  
        for i, tr in enumerate(soup.select('tr')):
    
            row_data = [td.text for td in tr.select('td, th') if td.text]
    
            if not row_data:
                continue
    
            if len(row_data) < 12:
                row_data = ['X'] + row_data
    
            for j, td in enumerate(row_data):
                if j==0:
                    print('{: >30}'.format(td), end='|')
                else:
                    print('{: ^12}'.format(td), end='|')
            print()
      
    # Save the data tables to a TXT file
    # Open a file with access mode 'a'
    file_object = open('testing aapl data.txt', 'a')
    # Append data at the end of file
    file_object.write(str(print_table(soup1))+"\n")
    file_object.write(str(print_table(soup2))+"\n")
    # Close the file
    file_object.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function, `print_table`, formats everthing on the go and passes everything to the console and nothing is kept or returned to be put into a file. As `print_table` doesn't return anything, so `None` is given.

A solution to this could be to create a string `finaltext` and concatenate everything that will be printed together after formatting it, then print `finaltext`, then return that string for any other use

The following script is the solution implemented as well as some other improvements

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json

#Only needs to be made once, as the 'for' loop will re-create it repeated
def print_table(soup):
    finaltext = ''
    for i, tr in enumerate(soup.select('tr')):
        row_data = [td.text for td in tr.select('td, th') if td.text]
        if not row_data:
            continue
    
        if len(row_data) < 12:
            row_data = ['X'] + row_data
    
        for j, td in enumerate(row_data):
            if j==0:
                finaltext += '{: >30}'.format(td) + '|'
            else:
                finaltext += '{: ^12}'.format(td) + '|'
        finaltext += '\n'
    print(finaltext)
    return finaltext

# Input
thislist = ["AAPL"]
for symbol in thislist:
    print ('Getting data for ' + symbol + '...\n')

    # Set up scraper
    url1 = ("http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getFinancePart.html?&callback=xxx&t=" + symbol.lower())
    url2 = ("http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getKeyStatPart.html?&callback=xxx&t=" + symbol.lower())
    
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(json.loads(re.findall(r'xxx\((.*)\)', requests.get(url1).text)[0])['componentData'], 'lxml')
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(json.loads(re.findall(r'xxx\((.*)\)', requests.get(url2).text)[0])['componentData'], 'lxml')
      
    # Save the data tables to a TXT file
    # Open a file with access mode 'a'
    file_object = open('testing_aapl_data.txt', 'a') # Habit of mine to not have spaces in filenames
    # Append data at the end of file
    file_object.write(str(print_table(soup1))+"\n")
    file_object.write(str(print_table(soup2))+"\n")
    # Close the file
    file_object.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much MOStudios! It is perfect!